# Easy way (with out eval) to turn a passed string into an object refereance in JS?

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have a in page function:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" onclick="doSomething(this.id)" id="someVar" alt="blah" />
```

and I have a class set up:

```
function anObject(someProp)
{
this.someProp=someProp;
}
someVar=anObject("prop");
```

Where I have trouble is in the doSomething function:

```
function doSomething(theObject)
{
alert(theObject.someProp); //this is treated as "someVar".someProp as far as I can tell instead of someVar.someProp
}
```

Basically, I would like to be able to use that reference as an object reference instead of a string, is there an easy way to do this without eval?

Also is there some way to ensure the oppisite, that it is treated as a string instead of an object?

**EDIT: I am attempting to reference the object with the same name as the image's ID NOT the image itself.**

Comment: mind me asking, what is the idea behind this type of functionality?

Comment: Sure, I am just messing with the idea of JavaScript functions as objects similar to C++ or C#. Mostly, for self education. I have a pretty long program that is just going to have a ball bounce or as many balls I call as objects in the browser. I can post it if you like, but the rest of the code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a collection object:

```
// Create an object with a property 'someProp', and return it
// (No messing with 'this')
function createSomeObject(someProp) {
  return {
    someProp: someProp
  };
}

// Keep a collection of variables
var someVars = {};
someVars.someVar = createSomeObject('prop');
someVars.otherVar = createSomeObject('prop2');
```

So you can reference them like this:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" onclick="doSomething(this)" id="someVar" alt="blah" />
```

And then you can get the original object like this:

```
function doSomething(imageElement) {
    var someVar = someVars[imageElement.id];
    alert(someVar.someProp); // this will return "prop"
}
```

Comment: Excellent, This is what I was looking for. But I do have to keep a global of someVars though? Hmmmmm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In this setup, you would indeed need to keep `someVars` global.  Alternatively, you could also attach the Javascript object to the HTMLImage element -- though I can’t remember if that’s good practice or not, and why (not).

Comment: You could avoid most global vars by using closures (e.g. using a factory constructor, which could return a single object that has access to all private variables).  But you will always need at least one global variable, for public access.

Answer (score 2):

```
doSomething(this)
```

drop the .id that will give you ref to the actual DOM element as an object

Comment: @K lvanav I believe that would cause my function to reference the image, not the object with the same name as the image's ID. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: yes the image as an object, do you want to have another object referenced to the image property?

Comment: @K lvanav Yes, if you take a look at my code I posted, the object is created at: someVar=anObject("prop");

Comment: looking at your update, in that case you will need eval to ref the object when you have the name of it as string

Answer (score 1):

Well you are passing a string (this.id) instead of an object to your function.
Should be:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" onclick="doSomething(this)" id="someVar" alt="blah" />
```

Comment: Same as I said for K Ivanov: I believe that would cause my function to reference the image, not the object with the same name as the image's ID. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: I see. it is unclear that you do have an object called `someVar`. You should then include the rest of your code.

Comment: This is all I require above. Right now, if you run the code above it will yield undefined where I would like it to yield "prop"